# DBNavigator - Connection Error - Unrecognised Session Property - 'v$session.program' in PyCharm

Tags: database, pycharm, presto

I am trying to connect the to the presto data store using presto driver.

When I try to **test connection**, it fails with error [image]

To isolate if it was connection configuration issue, I tried connecting with DBeaver, and it connects successfully.

So it is not a connection string issue.

By the look of the error signature, somehow DBNavigator is **injecting properties** in connection property that are **not** required by the connection.
I am not able to identify where is this getting added.
I tried digging thru the DBNavigator settings 1 by 1, could not find any thing.

Some configuration details:

- DRIVER: `io.prestosql:presto-jdbc:RELEASE`
- using `presto-jdbc-348.jar` as driver library
- jdbc url: `jdbc:presto://presto.x.x.run:80/hive`
- Database type : `Generic`

Comment: This question has a problem, it doesn't show one single configuration you are using in trying to connect to the DB, it only shows the error message. So there's no way to try and reproduce this. Can you edit the question to include more specific details?

Comment: updated the question with additional details

Comment: I'm retracting my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue about this https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/9254
You can try to patch presto to ignore unknown JDBC properties:
https://github.com/vloup/presto/commit/3574e6944a5fc41f4adfe07168e990db94e531f4

I do not know, why this patch was not applied.

Comment: I don't have a lot of control on the Presto build given that is a central server. Is there something that I can do at connection level?

Comment: or did you mean to patch the presto jar, that I am using for connecting?

Comment: Yes, this patch is for presto JDBC driver jar. you will patch and build presto-jdbc module.

Comment: Let me try this